# Seaborn scatterplot when x and y are the same variable with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, facet

I have this dataset:

```
dat = []

import numpy as np
import math

for r in range(0,100):
    for c1 in ["A", "B"]:
        for c2 in ["x", "y", "z"]:
            rec = {
                "cat1": c1,
                "cat2" : c2,
                "value" : np.random.rand(1)[0]
            }
            dat.append(rec)

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
df
```

```
    cat1    cat2    value
0   A   x   0.146189
1   A   y   0.187912
2   A   z   0.426760
3   B   x   0.553488
4   B   y   0.157560
...     ...     ...     ...
595     A   y   0.708308
596     A   z   0.921557
597     B   x   0.347119
598     B   y   0.232549
599     B   z   0.652732

600 rows × 3 columns
```

I can plot good looking histograms:

```
grid = sns.displot(
    df, 
    x="value", 
    col="cat1", 
    row="cat2",
    facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
)
for ax in grid.axes.flat:
    ax.axvline(0, 0, 1, color="black", lw=1, linestyle="--")
```

[image]

But I'm looking for a scatterplot where "x" = "value" when cat1=="A" and "y" = "value" when cat1=="B".

This does not do what I want:

```
sns.relplot(
    data=df,
    x=df.query("cat1 == 'A'")['value'],
    y=df.query("cat1 == 'B'")['value'],
    col="cat1",    
    row="cat2",    
    facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
    kind="scatter"
)
```

[image]

Nor this:

```
sns.relplot(
    data=df,
    x='value',
    y='value',
    col="cat1",    
    row="cat2",    
    facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
    kind="scatter"
)
```

[image]

I want it to look more like this:

[image]

Both the x and y are plotting the "value" variable, but they are split on whether cat1="A" or cat1="B".  This particular graph is produced with subplots rather than facets---which is why the vertical line at 0 does not line up (and I'm trying to use a faceted scatterplot here to get precisely that).

Comment: To line up the subplots, you can use `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)`